# Displaying instant search results with lunr.js

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript component of a plugin for the [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) static site generator that creates instant search results as you type into a search box.

Any comments on organization and structure of the code would be appreciated, especially with respect to binding to DOM events. I work primarily in Python, so I'm still learning proper javascript idioms.

The relevant HTML is basically

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="ls_search-field" placeholder="Search API" />
  <ul id="ls_search-results"></ul>
</form>
```

And the javascript is

```
// searchbox.js
(function ($, lunr, Search, DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS) {
    "use strict";

    var store = Search.store,
        index = null;

    lunr.tokenizer.seperator = '.';
    index = lunr(function () {
        this.field('prefix');
        this.field('name', { boost: 10 });
        this.ref('id');
    });

    $.each(store, function (id, value) {
        index.add({
            id: id,
            name: value.name,
            prefix: value.prefix
        });
    });

    $("#ls_search-field")
        .keyup(function (event) {
            onKeyUp(event);
        })
        .keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var active = $('#ls_search-results li a.hover')[0];
                active.click();
            }
        })
        .focusout(function () {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/13980492/1079728
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('.results').hide();
            }, 100);
        })
        .focusin(function () {
            if ($('#ls_search-results li').length > 0) {
                $('#ls_search-results').show();
            }
        });

    function onKeyUp(event) {
        var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which,
            query = $("#ls_search-field").val(),
            ul = $('#ls_search-results'),
            i = 0,
            results = null;

        if (keycode === 13) {
            return;
        }
        if (keycode === 40 || keycode === 38) {
            return handleKeyboardNavigation(keycode);
        }
        if (query === '') {
            ul.empty().hide();
            return;
        }

        results = index.search(query);
        ul.show();

        if (results.length === 0) {
            ul.empty().append($('<li><a href="#">No results found</a></li>'));
            return;
        }

        ul.empty();
        for (i = 0; i < Math.min(results.length, 5); i += 1) {
            ul.append(createResultListElement(store[results[i].ref]));
        }
    }  // end onKeyUp


    function handleKeyboardNavigation(keycode) {
        var ul = $('#ls_search-results'),
            active = $(ul.find('li a.hover')[0]);

        if (keycode === 40) {
            // next
            if (!active.length) {
                $(ul.find('li a')[0]).addClass('hover');
            } else {
                active.removeClass('hover');
                active.parent().next().find('a').addClass('hover');
            }
        } else if (keycode === 38) {
            // prev
            active.removeClass('hover');
            active.parent().prev().find('a').addClass('hover');
        }
    }  // end handleKeyboardNavigation

    function buildHref(s) {
        return DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.URL_ROOT + s.filename +
               DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS.FILE_SUFFIX +
               '#' + s.prefix + '.' + s.name;
    } // end buildHref


    function createResultListElement(s) {
        var prefix = (s.objtype === "py:method") ? (s.last_prefix + ".") : "",
            ul = $('#ls_search-results');

        return $('<li>')
            .append($('<a>')
                .attr('href', buildHref(s))
                .text(prefix + s.name)
                .mouseenter(function () {
                    ul.find('li a').removeClass('hover');
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                })
                .mouseleave(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('hover');
                })
                );
    } // end createResultListElement

}($, lunr, Search, DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS));
```

The fact that the data used to populate the index comes in the global object `Search.store` is something that I can't really work around, given the other moving parts in the system.

A couple potential questions or issues:

- I tried to structure the code similar to the "revealing module pattern",
  with private methods, but it doesn't ever return an object containing
  any public methods. Is that a problem?
- I guess this is tied to specific ids to hook into the DOM. Is it worth
  the added complexity to factor those out and make a fully "reusable"
  component?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.